# What should I do with this SPARQL result in Jena?

Tags: semantic-web, sparql, jena

I created a simple query to show subjects with value of a DataType property. 
This query runs in Protege 3.4.3. But when I run in Jena I receive this title "com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetStream@16be68f". Why?
this is my query:

```
PREFIX VB: <http://VBnet#>
SELECT ?x ?y
WHERE {
  ?x rdf:type VB:LearnerInformation .
  ?x VB:Name ?y
}
```

*LearnerInformation* is one class and 
*Name* is a Datatype property.

Comment: can you edit your question providing some sample data. It might be that Protege is doing some sort level of reasoning and Jena is not doing it, and therefore Jena doesn't give you any answers.

Answer (score 5):

You have received a set of results, which is represented by a [ResultSet](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ResultSet.html). You can step through it as follows:

```
ResultSet results = ... // result of query
while (results.hasNext()) {
  QuerySolution soln = results.next();
  System.err.printf("X is '%s'\n", soln.getResource("x"));
  System.err.printf("Y is '%s'\n", soln.getLiteral("y"));
}
```

Note that the results are structured objects themselves.

Comment: My friend thanks for your answer.But already i used this code in my programming.i don't know why my query in jena doesn't has any output while in Protege i can see the output!??

Comment: @saman @user205512 could it be that Jena is not doing any reasoning and Protege is giving answers based on some sort level of reasoning ??

Comment: The query is illegal.  rdf: is not defined.  This suggests your question/example is not what you are actually running.